# How do I create more order types?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

This might be a dumb question, but what is the best way to add new "order types" in Magento? For example, when we gift an order, or it's internal, or we manually create it for any number of reasons.

I figured it would be super easy (like creating new order statuses), but it's not.

If I wanted to just add a new column to the sales_flat_order table, would that be a good approach? I've only added new tables, never changed one part of the core.